# how to size next js 13 images

Tags: html, css, next.js, responsive-design

I am building a responsive website and I have been struggling to get the sizing right.

This is how my image looks like on mobile, which is correct:

[image]

Now when I switch over to desktop screen view, the image is way too big.

[image]

I will try describe how I want the image to behave:

On mobile screen on bottom of screen, just like it is now.

On Desktop screen, I want to image on bottom right corner of the current view. Basically in the red rectangle I have drawn. I don't want it to have it fixed height and width because I need it to grow and shrink responsively.

this is the relevant html code

```html
<section class="page_hero-section__MZdi7">
   <div class="page_hero-con__ijIdx">
      <a>particulieren</a>
      <h2>(zorg-)organisaties</h2>
      <p>Ontlast de werkvloer. Onze x komen op locatie en zorgen voor een stralende lach voor clienten én medewerkers.</p>
      <button>werkwijze</button><button>get started</button>
   </div>
   <div class="page_hero-join-con__AkBR0">
      <Image alt="cool girl with colorful glasses"
src={coolGirlGlasses}
 \>
      <div>
         <p>werken bij ons?</p>
         <span>
            <hr>
         </span>
         <a>join the crew</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="page_hero-werkwijze__IoSuu">
      <p>werkwijze</p>
      <div class="page_hero-werkwijze-line__ccNUj"></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

this is the relevant css

```css
.hero-section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

  img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

If i give the image a height of 100% it is bigger than its container.
I have also  tried giving the image object-fit: contain but it changed nothing.

Comment: Maybe size it based on your typography. `img { width: min(20rem, 100vw) }`

Comment: First of all, you lost a *< /image>* tag and that may make this code not working in some cases. Second, I tested the code, and it loses the photo and some CSS styles, please add them.

Answer (score 1):

fixed it.

By adding `flex: 1` to the parent element `hero-join-con` of the `img` and adding `fill={true}` on the `<Image />` react element and adding `object-fit: contain` and `object-position: right bottom` to `hero-con-join img`.

`object-fit` didn't work out earlier because I was missing the `fill={true}` property.